# Jquery - How to add dynamic IDs and for text for respective labels

Tags: jquery, listitem

I have one list items with check boxes which are dynamically loading from back-end stuff.

Here is the HTML constructor I have in my browser view.

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /><label>Details 1</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /><label>Details 2</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /><label>Details 3</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /><label>Details 4</label></li>
    .... and so on
</ul>
```

The number of lists can be changed any point of time according to the dynamic control.

The thing is, I want to add 'ID' for check boxes incrementally and have to add 'for' attribute for respective label container.  Needless to say that the same id name has to be applied for respective label attribute also.

How do I achieve this by jQuery.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will the checkboxes that you load from the backend also have IDs?

Comment: Note that you don't *need* to use `id` and `for`, you could do this: `<li><label><input type="checkbox" />Details 1</label></li>` When the checkbox is *inside* its label, the relationship is implicit.

Comment: @ T.J.Crowder: We can't change the html constructor as we wish.  Everything is loading from back-end...

Comment: @ Bojan:  Yes all things are loading from backend without having any ID references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var listItems = $('ul li');
listItems.each(function(idx, li) {
    $(this).find('input').attr('id','chkbox'+idx);
    $(this).find('label').attr('for','chkbox'+idx);
});
```

I used the `each` from jquery, check this out no matter any number of list items could be used there.

[1]:

```js
var listItems = $("ul li");
listItems.each(function(idx, li) {
    $(this).find('input').attr('id','chkbox'+idx);
    $(this).find('label').attr('for','chkbox'+idx);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /><label>Details 1</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /><label>Details 2</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /><label>Details 3</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /><label>Details 4</label></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u5epnf5e/)**

use

in jquery

```
var countValueYouSet=1;
    $("ul li ").each(function(){
        $('input').attr('id',countValueYouSet);
        $('label').prop('for',countValueYouSet);

        countValueYouSet++;
    });
```

Comment: Nope, we can't append from jquery.  Already loaded in browser.

Comment: WHY DOWNVOTES ?? downvoter please comment . ITS WORKING SOLUTION , CHECK FIDDLE !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

Find all labels that follow an `input` element and that do not have a `for` attribute,  then create an id and assign it to their `for` attribute and to the `id` of the previous element (*the `input`*).

```
$('input + label:not([for])').each(function(index, item){
   var id = 'checkbox-' + index,
       label = $(this);
   label.prop('for', id )
        .prev().prop('id', id);
});
```

```js
$('input + label:not([for])').each(function(index, item){
  
  var id = 'checkbox-' + index,
      label = $(this);
  
  label.prop('for', id )
       .prev().prop('id', id);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /><label>Details 1</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /><label>Details 2</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /><label>Details 3</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" /><label>Details 4</label></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two obvious options, the first is to add `id` and `for`:

```js
$('input').prop('id', function(i) {
  var id = 'input' + i;
  $(this).next('label').attr('for', id);
  return id;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label>Details 1</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label>Details 2</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label>Details 3</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label>Details 4</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The second is to simply move the `input` inside the `label`:

```js
$('input').each(function() {
  $(this).prependTo(this.nextElementSibling);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label>Details 1</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label>Details 2</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label>Details 3</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label>Details 4</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`node.nextElementSibling`](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/element.nextElementSibling.html).
- jQuery:

  - [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
  - [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
  - [`prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/).
  - [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).